# How to calculate numeric order of data using dates and time in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

I've two columns, one with time and another with date.

I want to add a new column 'Order' indicating the order in numbers of each row data according to those time and date columns so the order #1 corresponds to the data that was collected first and so on.

How can I get that with a cell function for the 'Order' column?

And whether this is feasible if the dates and times are not sorted in the original file. The formula that I've tried is not ordering from the oldest date to the most recent date and time ('Order' #1 should be the oldest date and time and so on). For example:

[image]

It should be like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Version 2310 (Build 16924.20150)

Comment: Try my answer. It seems, you may count unique `Data Point` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UNIQUE()` function.

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE($C$2:$D2))
```

For dynamic spill results, try-

```
=MAP(D2:D12,LAMBDA(x,ROWS(UNIQUE($C$2:x))))
```

[image]

As per above revised sample data, please try-

```
=XMATCH(CONCAT(A2:B2),BYROW(UNIQUE($A$2:$B$11),LAMBDA(r,CONCAT(r))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr, but this does not work if dates are randomly located across the column (i.e., not in increasing order as the example shows). How do I create a similar formula that gives an 'Order' value of one to the earliest date (day and time) and from there starts to increase with day and time. I've tried the code and only works if the dates and times are ordered in increasing order.

Comment: Then you may need `SORT()` function. Can you put an example what you described in comment?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've updated the question with another example. I have many columns/rows and will probably need to filter a lot of data, so just trying to find a quick way to solve this issue.

Comment: @SergioNolazco From your given 2nd sample, same formula should work. What result are you getting?

Comment: I have updated the question and provide an example in which the formula is not giving the correct order. thanks.

Comment: @SergioNolazco Would you please try `=XMATCH(CONCAT(A2:B2),BYROW(UNIQUE($A$2:$B$11),LAMBDA(r,CONCAT(r))))`.

Comment: IF you see you table image, 02/22/2023 14:15 is a closest date and time than 02/20/23 14:15, but the order numbers are not indicating that accordingly. Also, 02/22/23 time 14:15 is a closest date and time than 14:02, and the order number is not reflecting that.

Comment: @SergioNolazco Try this one with sort `=XMATCH(A2+B2,UNIQUE(SORT($A$2:$A$11+$B$2:$B$11)))`.

Comment: Same incorrect result. Is there a way to sort oldest to newest day in excel if I have date and time in the same cell? It seems that it only sorts by date.

Comment: Would you please show your desired output from current sample screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256108/discussion-between-sergio-nolazco-and-harun24hr).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it, it was simpler than I thought.

**Step one:** Sorting the data by Date and Time

Data > Sort

[image]

**Step 2:** Apply the first formula that Harun24hr provided in the comments

**=ROWS(UNIQUE($A$2:$B2))**

Done!